# Dynamic funciton call on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Is it possible to have different function in ng-click depending the controller ( page ) loaded?

```
<a ng-click="removeEvent(event)" class="top_menu_link"> REMOVE</a>
```

Say i want the same button to perform a remove action but on different models. Say event, person, etc. So this button is outside the ng-view.

So my guess is to call a function with a paramenter like `removeItem('person')` then have a set of if elses. Wondering if there is a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<a ng-click="fn.removeEvent(event)" class="top_menu_link"> REMOVE</a>
```

Then, in the controller that this anchor is on, define `fn`:

```
$scope.fn = {};
```

In the individual pages (/models), set `removeEvent`:

```
$scope.fn.removeEvent = function(event){
    // Model-specific stuff
};
```

Because you're setting the function on a object that's already defined in the parent scope, you can simply override the function, while the anchor in the parent scope still has a reference to the function.

P.S: You may want to hide the anchor if the function isn't set:

```
<a ng-if="fn.removeEvent" ng-click="fn.removeEvent(event)" class="top_menu_link"> REMOVE</a>
```